# extracting a text from some strings with python

Tags: python, regex, substring

if i have these strings:

```
string1 = "10th floor, Shindaisou Building, 2-10-7 Dogenzaka, Shibuya-ku , Tokyo 150-0043"
string2 = "2-176-1 Takasu Misato-shi, Saitama-ken, 341-0037 Japan"
string3 = "5-6-60 Higashikonoike-cho, Higashi-Osaka-shi, Osaka 578-0973"
```

I need to extract the third number of the three numbers connected with dashes, the output should look like this:

```
string1 Output: 7
string2 Output: 1
string3 Output: 60
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Are those the only strings you have? Can one assume in general that those dashes are the first dashes that will appear in the string? Do you know how to use regex?

Comment: What have you already tried to do that? Do you need help with something or expect to just get a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import  re

string1 = "10th floor, Shindaisou Building, 2-10-7 Dogenzaka, Shibuya-ku , Tokyo 150-0043"
string2 = "2-176-1 Takasu Misato-shi, Saitama-ken, 341-0037 Japan"
string3 = "5-6-60 Higashikonoike-cho, Higashi-Osaka-shi, Osaka 578-0973"

ptrn = re.compile(r"\d+\-\d+\-(\d+)")
for i in (string1, string2, string3):
    m = ptrn.search(i)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
7
1
60
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `re.findall` here:

```py
string1 = "10th floor, Shindaisou Building, 2-10-7 Dogenzaka, Shibuya-ku , Tokyo 150-0043"
matches = re.findall(r'\b\d+-\d+-(\d+)\b', string1)
print(matches[0])  # prints 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best result but it works:

```
def function(string):
    string = string.split()
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        count = 0
        for j in range(0,len(string[i])):
            if string[i][j] == '-':
                count += 1
        if count == 2:
            result = string[i].split('-')[2]
            if result.isdigit():
                return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = r'\d+\-[0-9]*\-(\d+)'
for i in (string1, string2, string3):
    res = re.findall(pattern, i)
    print(''.join(res))

    output
    # 7
    # 1
    # 60
```